# Windows 11 boots slowly (tens of minutes), with Boot Degradation (ID: 101) in Event Viewer: Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational

Tags: windows, boot, performance, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

My Windows 11 install boots slowly, sometimes taking tens of minutes, sometimes an hour or more. To rule out common issues, I have already performed the following:

1. Full virus scan (no issues detected)
2. Boot in Safe Mode (slowness persisted)
3. Clean boot (slowness persisted)
4. Advanced startup - Startup Repair (no issues detected)
5. Checked SSD health (no issues)
6. SFC /scannow (no issues detected)
7. DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth (no issues detected)
8. Windows in-place repair from ISO (slowness persisted)
9. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System set VerboseStatus=1 (no changes from previous behavior)

With no other ideas, I checked the Event Viewer, in the Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational log. To my surprise, I found the following "Boot degradation" events (ID: 101). The only one of these that isn't a Windows system process is [0patch](https://0patch.com), which is a lightweight zero-day vulnerability patching service that I've run for years without any issue. Also worth noting that while the "Critical" event, "Boot Performance Monitoring," indicates that boot took about 2 minutes, it definitely took longer than that (The majority of the time the computer was on a completely black screen with just the Power indicator and Drive LEDs lit).

I have no idea what could be causing these programs to boot up so slowly. Is there anything I can do to improve this that I haven't already done?

```
Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Description:
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   LogonUI.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Windows Logon User Interface Host
     Version        :   10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
     Total Time     :   843ms
     Degradation Time   :   43ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Description:
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   svchost.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Host Process for Windows Services
     Version        :   10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
     Total Time     :   1227ms
     Degradation Time   :   227ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Description: 
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   dwm.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Desktop Window Manager
     Version        :   10.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
     Total Time     :   1790ms
     Degradation Time   :   990ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Description:
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   0patchScanner.exe
     Friendly Name      :   0patch Scanner
     Version        :   22.11.11.10550
     Total Time     :   6663ms
     Degradation Time   :   1663ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Description:
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   SearchIndexer.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Microsoft Windows Search Indexer
     Version        :   7.0.22621.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
     Total Time     :   11368ms
     Degradation Time   :   6368ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      101
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Warning
Description:
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name      :   OneDrive.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Microsoft OneDrive
     Version        :   23.174.0820.0003
     Total Time     :   12873ms
     Degradation Time   :   7873ms
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z

Date:          9/12/2023 12:07:28 PM
Event ID:      100
Task Category: Boot Performance Monitoring
Level:         Critical
Description:
Windows has started up: 
     Boot Duration      :   118936ms
     IsDegradation      :   false
     Incident Time (UTC)    :   ‎2023‎-‎09‎-‎12T16:05:02.857236200Z
```

(Here is a [PasteBin link](https://pastebin.com/2vmggYDv) to the XML of the Events, if that's more helpful)

Comment: A vanilla Windows 11 system on SSD will be up and running in 2 or 3 minutes.  Is 0patch fully Windows 11 compliant?  Can it be removed to test?

Comment: It is compliant, and it was disabled during both Safe Boot and Clean Boot... But I can uninstall it anyway to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I would suggest to undo  everything 0patch patched in your Windows and uninstall it.

Comment: Yeah, did that. As expected, did not make a lick of difference. This is a Windows problem.

Comment: Okay, it may actually have been a hardware problem because the next day it stopped booting completely, not even into BIOS. Did the whole nine yards of disconnecting battery, drive, and RAM, disconnecting CMOS battery and clearing RTC, even replaced the CMOS battery. I think it's a mobo issue. The slow startup times this question was originally about were probably just a symptom of that.